# How to pass bulk of json objects into Json array

Tags: android, json, arraylist, arrays

Hi can any one help for this issue, i am not able to pass arraylist of values in bellow json array.

please help me.

Ex values:

```
Arraylist<String> list_values = new Arraylist<String>();
list_values.add(111);
list_values.add(222);
list_values.add(333);

Arraylist<String> list_labeltext = new Arraylist<String>();
list_labeltext.add("Mileage Entry");
list_labeltext.add("Tip Amount");
list_labeltext.add("Travel Time");

Arraylist<String> list_optionId = new Arraylist<String>();
list_optionId.add("1");
list_optionId.add("2");
list_optionId.add("3");
```

i want pass above array list values in json array like this:

```
ClockOUTEmployeeReponse":[{"Response":[{"Response":[{"Value":"111"}],"LabelText":"Mileage Entry","ClockOUTOptionId":2},{"Response":[{"Value":"222"}],"LabelText":"Tip Amount","ClockOUTOptionId":4},{"Response":[{"Value":"333"}],"LabelText":"Travel Time","ClockOUTOptionId":3}]
```

My Code is as follows:

```
JSONObject parentData = new JSONObject();
JSONArray req_parameters = new JSONArray();
JSONObject req_clockout_obj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray req_arr = new JSONArray();
JSONObject value = new JSONObject();

req_clockout_obj.put("ClockOUTOptionId", 1);
req_clockout_obj.put("LabelText", labelText);
for (int i = 0; i < list_values.size; i++) {

    if (i == 0) {

        value.put("Value", list_values.get(0));

        req_arr.put(value);

        req_clockout_obj.put("Response", req_arr);

    } else if (i == 1) {

        value.put("Value", list_values.get(1));

        req_arr.put(value);

        req_clockout_obj.put("Response", req_arr);

    } else if (i == 2) {

        value.put("Value", list_values.get(2));

        req_arr.put(value);

        req_clockout_obj.put("Response", req_arr);

    }

}
req_parameters.put(req_clockout_obj);
parentData.put("ClockOUTEmployeeReponse", req_parameters);
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: please see the above code, i added some code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Best way to implement this is using a Model Class and fetch data in a instance of that Model(POJO) then convert that into json string.

For this You need GSON library.**

Steps :
         1. Make a POJO(Model Class) of according to you json format.
         2. Then fetch data in a object of that POJO.
         3. Then U can convert that POJO's object into json using

```
DataObject obj = new DataObject();
Gson gson = new Gson();

// convert java object to JSON format,
// and returned as JSON formatted string
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

Please follow the following link :
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

**Please use this, If you need any help then let me know.**